# X.PagedList loses formatting after AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, pagedlist

Using the UnobtrusiveAjax example [here](https://github.com/kpi-ua/X.PagedList/tree/master/src/X.PagedList.Mvc.Example/Views/UnobtrusiveAjax), I am attempting to use a little Bootstrap CSS.  Everything is formatted and working fine, except that when I use the pager, the updated page has no formatting and even the pager is gone.

VIEW - INDEX

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Unobtrusive Ajax";
}
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@Styles.Render("~/Content/PagedList.css")

<div id="unobtrusive">
    <div class="blog_masonry_3col">
        <div class="container content grid-boxes">
            @Html.Partial("UnobtrusiveAjax_Partial")
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-5">
            @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.Names, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "unobtrusive", OnComplete = "PagedOnComplete" }))
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="oncomplete"></div>

@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function PagedOnComplete(obj) {
            console.log(obj);
            var $oncomplete = $('#oncomplete');
            $oncomplete
                .text('Paging operation completed.')
                .css('backgroundColor', 'yellow')
                .fadeOut({complete: function () {
                    $oncomplete.css('backgroundColor', 'transparent').text('').show();
                }});
        }
    </script>
}
```

VIEW - UnobtrusiveAjax_Partial

```
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;

<div id="names" start="@ViewBag.Names.FirstItemOnPage">
    @foreach (var i in ViewBag.Names)
    {
        @*<li>@i.Title</li>*@
        <div class="grid-boxes-in">
            <div class="grid-boxes-caption">               
                <p>@i</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Controller

```
public class Test2Controller : BaseController
    {
        public ActionResult Index(int? page)
        {
            var listPaged = GetPagedNames(page); // GetPagedNames is found in BaseController
            if (listPaged == null)
                return HttpNotFound();

            ViewBag.Names = listPaged;
            return Request.IsAjaxRequest()
                ? (ActionResult)PartialView("UnobtrusiveAjax_Partial")
                : View();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "unobtrusive" div contains the pager that is making the ajax call.

You specify that when making an ajax call to place the returned HTML in the "unobtrusive" div. However, the returned HTML does not have a pager, so it is removing the pager.

So rather than target that div, target the div where the contents will be placed and does not have the pager:

```
<div id="unobtrusive">
    <div class="blog_masonry_3col">
        <div class="container content grid-boxes" id="divToReplace">
            @Html.Partial("UnobtrusiveAjax_Partial")
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-5">
            @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.Names, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "divToReplace", OnComplete = "PagedOnComplete" }))
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will take care of the div disappearing, but it might also fix the formatting as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, the formatting is still off.  I see where' you're going with this though, so I'll keep trying thx.